# How to differentiate between the result sets retrieved for multiple OR conditions?

Tags: mysql, where

I've a huge dataset which I'm quering with multiple OR conditions. Though I'm getting all the results, but I want to differentiate between the results that are retrieved for a certain where condition. Is there any way to do that? Here is an example -

```
Select * from table where col1 like '%text1%' or col1 like '%text2%'
```

This query is retrieving entire matching dataset, but how can I differentiate between the results that are matching text1 or text2? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Imagine my col1 has 500+words of text. Then it will be very difficult to identify the matching dataset. I know I can run each where condition separately, but looking for an approach that can meet my expectation with a single query. Also updated the given query.

Answer (score 2):

Typically I recommend materialising your resultset when this scenario has come up. Since queries of this nature are usually pretty broad and analytical (read: non-performant), this approach has the benefit of

- reducing editing requirements (do you want to add the line to both the `select` *and* `where` clauses for each evaluation?)
- snapshotting the underlying data for debugging
- capturing "*missed*" rows from the underlying data that you thought you *should have* captured

Avoid:

```sql
Select 
    if(col1 like '%text1%',TRUE,FALSE) as a,
    if(col1 like '%text2%',TRUE,FALSE) as b,
    col1 
from table 
where col1 like '%text1%' 
   or col1 like '%text2%'
```

Prefer:

```sql
create temporary table foo as (
    Select 
        if(col1 like '%text1%',TRUE,FALSE) as a,
        if(col1 like '%text2%',TRUE,FALSE) as b,
        col1 
    from table 
);

select * 
from foo
where a
   or b;
```

Play with a demo of this approach [on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0009afa8d940ccaac92832a37cf368e)

Answer (score 1):

Only matched records with matched patterns list:

```
WITH 
phrases AS (SELECT 'Phrase containing "text1" substring' phrase UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Phrase containing "text2" substring' UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Phrase containing "text1" and "text2" substrings' UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Phrase not containing desured substrings'),
patterns AS (SELECT '%text1%' pattern UNION ALL
             SELECT '%text2%')
SELECT ph.phrase, GROUP_CONCAT(pa.pattern) matched_patterns
FROM phrases ph
JOIN patterns pa ON ph.phrase LIKE pa.pattern
GROUP BY ph.phrase
```

All records with the info about matched patterns list:

```
WITH 
phrases AS (SELECT 'Phrase containing "text1" substring' phrase UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Phrase containing "text2" substring' UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Phrase containing "text1" and "text2" substrings' UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Phrase not containing desured substrings'),
patterns AS (SELECT '%text1%' pattern UNION ALL
             SELECT '%text2%')
SELECT ph.phrase, COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(pa.pattern), 'none') matched_patterns
FROM phrases ph
LEFT JOIN patterns pa ON ph.phrase LIKE pa.pattern
GROUP BY ph.phrase
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df4246559449320c62013844dc21b67b)